# How take Validation property from document types?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

How can I take from Property settings the validation?
I created a new document types and I wrote there regex and I want take the regex from **UmbracoApiController** I have the content from this page

```
IContent content = Services.ContentService.GetById(pageId);
```

But I don't found the validation object:
[image: validation regex]

**EDIT**

I found the result:

```
var contentType = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentTypeService.GetContentType(contentTypeId);
List<PropertyTypeCollection> propertyGroups = contentType.PropertyGroups.Select(s=>s.PropertyTypes).ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The validation property is, to the best of my knowledge, only for use in the backoffice, You would probably have to re-do it in front end or in your controller :-/

Comment: HI jannik,
And how can I approach it from backoffice (I new in umbraco thanks for help)

Comment: Approach it? Not sure what you mean. Whenever you insert a validation rule on a property, the validation should prevent you from typing in invalid data when you create or edit that content node. Doesn't it do that?

Comment: If I use umbraco forms thats works (but still need the data from UmbracoApiController ) thanks anyway